# iOS CoreBluetooth couldn't discover services on iPad Air

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm working on an application what connects to BLE peripherals.

It works fine on iPhone 5, 5s, 5c, but on iPad Air (iOS 7.1.1) when I call `[peripheral discoverServices:nil]` it disconnects with unexcepted error.

I also tried LightBlue app, it produces the same error.

Looks like an iOS bug, any ideas?

Comment: whats the error ? post it here.

Comment: Already tried rebooting the iPad? The Bluetooth stack crashes every now and then.

Comment: The error was: `The connection has timed out unexpectedly`

Comment: Thanks, the reboot helped.